# How to add object to document before returning it?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to solve the following problem:
After fetching a collection from Firestore via angularfire, I want to iterate through each document within these collection and than do a separate Firestore request to get a corresponding document which values I want to insert into the first document before returning the collection.

For example, there is a object called `ball` with the properties

```
interface Ball: {
  uid: string; 
  color: string;
}
```

And a object `player` with the properties

```
interface Player: {
  uid: string;
  correspondingBall: ball;
}
```

Within the Firestore collection, I save a document from type Player with the corresponding id from the corresponding ball (I hope you know what I mean).
Now, I access the the collection player

```
getRecentPlayers(): Observable<Player[]> {
    const players: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> = this.angularFirestore.collection<Player>('players');
    return players ? players.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(players => {
        return players.map(player => {
          const data = player.payload.doc.data() as Player;
          const correspondingBall: AngularFirestoreDocument<Ball> = this.angularFirestore.doc('balls/' + data.correspondingBall);
          correspondingBall ? correspondingBall.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(ball => {
              const data = ball.payload.data() as Ball;
              return data;
            })
          ) : null;
          return {...data, correspondingBall}
        })
      })
    ) : null;
  }
```

That way, I wouldn't work. Can someone help me?
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

in general the way is: make a consult (return an array of values), make a switchMap, create an array of observables, make a forkjoin, map with index to add the new properties. I go to code using simples gets

```
getPlayers().pipe(
  switchMap(players=>{
    //in players we has an array of player
    //create an array of observables with the array
    const obs=players.map(player=>getBall(player.ballId)
    //a switchMap must return an observable, so return a forkJoin
    return forkjoin(obs).pipe(
       //but we transform the result that is an array
       //with the values of getBall(1),getBall(2)..
       map((ball,index)=>{
          //concat the properties of players[index] with the ball
          return {...players[index],..ball}
       })
    )
  }
)).subscribe(res=>console.log(res))
```